# check jquery not and change other div inner

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(".productOptions a").click(function(){
    var datafilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.productOptions a').css( "color", "#898989" );
    $('.productOptions a').not('.'+datafilter).css( "color", "#eee" );

    if(!$('.productOptions a').is('.' + datafilter)){
        $('#urunDurum').html("true");
    }else{
        $('#urunDurum').html("false");
    }

    /* 
    if ($('.productOptions a.'+datafilter)) {
        $('#urunDurum').html( "yok" );
    }else{
        $('#urunDurum').html( "var" );
    }*/
}); 

$(".productOptions").on('click','li', function(){
    var datafilter = $(this).find("a[href]").attr('data-filter');
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
 </script>
```

when i click two active buttons i need true,  active and passive = false,  passive + passive = false. after i need change urunDurum div inner. check the link please http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3d7/

Comment: what is `if ($('button').not('.'+datafilter))` supposed to mean? Also you mean `$(this).data("filter")`

Comment: I think you want the `.is()` method like `if(!$('button').is('.' + datafilter))`, however looks like `$('button')` here should be `$(this)`.

Comment: i need check "clicked button data-filter = clicked class" true or false

Comment: You have no matching class with data-filter in your html. So, it's a bit about confusion.

Comment: Your example has no button that contains a class the same as its data-filter attribute?!

Comment: ok new jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3d7/
my style is working but true false doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle provided in comments of your question here http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3d7/,
I think you're looking for this code: Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Mh3d7/1/

```
 $(".productOptions a").click(function () {
     var datafilter = $(this).data('filter');
     $('.productOptions a').css("color", "#898989");
     $('.productOptions a').not('.' + datafilter).css("color", "#eee");

     if (!$(this).hasClass(datafilter)) {
         $('#urunDurum').html("true");
     } else {
         $('#urunDurum').html("false");
     }


 });
```